# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: gfortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

Hi so I'm trying to compile a Fortran code written by someone else in what I believe is F77 (.for extension). The error I'm getting is:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_random_", referenced from:
      _pms_ in ccx1qzWD.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm not posting the code now but I've been searching online for what this error even means so I can start searching for the solution but can't find any helpful information. I have no previous Fortran experience! Any help on the meaning of this error is really appreciated. I'm using a mac and the only section that includes the "random" is part of a subroutine:

```
DOUBLE PRECISION RANDOM

DO 1 J=1,M
      w(J)=dw+REAL(J*2-1)*dw/2.0
      W1=w(J)*w(J)*w(J)*w(J)*w(J)
      Vel1=Vel*Vel*Vel*Vel*W1/w(J)
      Vel1=-6844.0697/Vel1
      Gw(J)=0.77898/W1*EXP(Vel1)
      Phi(J)=RANDOM()*8.0*ATAN(1.0)
1     CONTINUE
```

I am using: gfortran SEASIM.FOR to compile

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: Ok i added the part of hte source code that m ust be causing the error (random doesn't come in anywhere else)

Answer (score 1):

OK, it definitely looks like you're not providing the linker with a library containing an implementation of `random`.  You could dig around and find such a library, modify your linkage, and see how that goes.  But it would be easier to replace the call to `random` with a call to the `gfortran` intrinsic `rand` which returns a number from a uniform distribution between `0` and `1`.  So that's what I suggest you do.  Consult the documentation for further details.

A better approach would be to use the now-standard `random_number` but that's a subroutine and would require more of a modification to your program.

I have a nagging suspicion that if the only step you take to build the program is to execute `gfortran SEASIM.FOR` at the command-line then you may be missing linking to other necessary libraries so I won't be surprised if you report failure.

This line

```
DOUBLE PRECISION RANDOM
```

declares that `RANDOM` is a `DOUBLE PRECISION` thing.  That it is a function returning a value rather than a variable holding a value is made clear by the later use of `RANDOM()`.  The compiler is indifferent to the location of the code implementing the routine, but the linker is not.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about a line that says:
DOUBLE PRECISION RANDOM

Is this line attempting to call an old library called RANDOM? I don't understand the syntax of this line and waht it means exactly (I'm googling like crazy but can't find anything helpful)